# Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value ""' on the control

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I need to set null value i.e., "" value on a control.But I am facing exception as below

"Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value ""' on the control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'Web'
ControlType:  'Edit'
Id:  'ctl00_ctl00_Content_PlanContent_ucParentDeferralRule_txtAutoEnrollAmt'
Name:  'ctl00$ctl00$Content$PlanContent$ucParentDeferralRule$txtAutoEnrollAmt'
TagName:  'INPUT'"

and the code is like,

Control.Text = "";

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup for the control in question?  The error message given means that you're trying to set a property that doesn't exist on that control.

Comment: <input name="ctl00$ctl00$Content$PlanContent$ucParentDeferralRule$txtAutoEnrollPercent" class="EditableTextBoxWhite TextBoxStyle percentage EditableTextBoxWhite" id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_PlanContent_ucParentDeferralRule_txtAutoEnrollPercent" style="width: 100px;" onkeypress="return alpha(event,numbers);" type="text" maxLength="6"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if we have:

```
public HtmlEdit EditField()
    {
        HtmlEdit control = new HtmlEdit(GlobalVariable.browser);
        control.SearchProperties["id"] = "ctl00_ctl00_Content_PlanContent_ucParentDeferralRule_txtAutoEnrollPercent";
        return control;
    }
```

we should be able to set the value as you did (using `EditField().Text = String.Empty`).  The fact that we can't means that there's a restriction on that field that won't accept that value as an input.  Check the code to see if it's restricted to numerical values, for example, or if the value.length cannot be < 1, etc.